# Interpolate Date Columns between two Dataframes Pandas

Tags: python, date, pandas, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate between two date columns from two dataframes in python pandas.

I would like to combine the **"EVENT"** columns "DrillDate"from the dfDrillTable to the **closest next occurance date** in the dfCompTable. The dfDrillTable has a "Drilldate" that will always occur **BEFORE** the dfCompTable "OpenDate". The dfDrillTable and dfCompTable **must** both be joined on "Name" but only dfDrillTable has a unique "EVENT" which I am trying to link the two dataframes on.

There are some well names that have EVENT data in the drillTable that do not exist in the dfCompTable, (and visa vera). I need these to still come into the table but as blanks where the values dont exist.

I have created two sample dataframes for reference below. Then a third to show the outcome I would like.

I know there are multiple ways to do this with outerjoins and this and that but I was just looking for the cleanest, most foolproof way of interpolating between two dates.

```
    #dfDrillTable

Name    EVENT   DrillDate
0   W1  E1  2000-01-01
1   W1  E2  2000-03-01
2   W2  E3  2000-04-01
3   W1  E4  2000-05-15
4   W2  E5  2000-01-10
5   W3  E6  2000-02-01
6   G1  E1  2000-02-02

    #dfCompTable
    Name    OpenDate
0   W1  2000-01-02
1   W1  2000-03-15
2   W1  2000-05-10
3   W1  2000-05-20
4   W2  2000-01-15
5   W3  2000-02-10
6   X1  2016-05-05


    #dfInterp Outcome


Name    EVENT   DrillDate   OpenDate
0   W1  E1  2000-01-01  2000-01-02
1   W1  E2  2000-03-01  2000-03-15
2   W1  E3  2000-04-01  2000-05-10
3   W1  E4  2000-05-15  2000-05-20
4   W2  E5  2000-01-10  2000-01-15
5   W3  E6  2000-02-01  2000-02-10
6   G1  E1  2000-01-10  NaT
7   X1      NaT 2016-05-05
```

here is the code to create the tables

```
# Two DataTables
raw_data = {'Name': ['W1', 'W1', 'W2', 'W1', 'W2','W3','G1'],
            'EVENT':['E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4', 'E5','E6','E1'],
        'DrillDate': ['01/01/2000', '03/01/2000', '04/01/2000', '05/15/2000', '01/10/2000','02/01/2000','02/02/2000']}
dfDrillTable = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Name','EVENT','DrillDate'])
dfDrillTable['DrillDate'] = pd.to_datetime(dfDrillTable['DrillDate'])
dfDrillTable

raw_data2 = {'Name': ['W1', 'W1', 'W1', 'W1', 'W2','W3','X1'],
        'OpenDate': ['01/02/2000', '03/15/2000', '05/10/2000', '05/20/2000', '01/15/2000','02/10/2000','05/05/2016']}
dfCompTable = pd.DataFrame(raw_data2, columns = ['Name','OpenDate'])
dfCompTable['OpenDate'] = pd.to_datetime(dfCompTable['OpenDate'])
dfCompTable
```

and the outcome:

```
# Hopefull Outcome
raw_data = {'Name': ['W1', 'W1', 'W1', 'W1', 'W2','W3','G1','X1'],
            'EVENT':['E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4', 'E5','E6','E1',''],
        'DrillDate': ['01/01/2000', '03/01/2000', '04/01/2000', '05/15/2000', '01/10/2000','02/01/2000','01/10/2000',''],
           'OpenDate': ['01/02/2000', '03/15/2000', '05/10/2000', '05/20/2000', '01/15/2000','02/10/2000','','05/05/2016']}
dfInterp = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Name','EVENT','DrillDate','OpenDate'])
dfInterp['DrillDate'] = pd.to_datetime(dfInterp['DrillDate'])
dfInterp['OpenDate'] = pd.to_datetime(dfInterp['OpenDate'])
dfInterp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use [`pd.merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html): <-- link to documentation

pd.merge_asof is new in version 0.19.0  Be sure you have the latest pandas installed.

```
dfInterp = pd.merge_asof(dfCompTable.sort_values(by="OpenDate")
                         ,dfDrillTable.sort_values(by="DrillDate")
                         ,left_on="OpenDate",right_on="DrillDate")

dfInterp[['Name_x','EVENT','DrillDate','OpenDate']].sort_values(by='Name_x')

  Name_x EVENT  DrillDate   OpenDate
0     W1    E1 2000-01-01 2000-01-02
3     W1    E2 2000-03-01 2000-03-15
4     W1    E3 2000-04-01 2000-05-10
5     W1    E4 2000-05-15 2000-05-20
1     W2    E5 2000-01-10 2000-01-15
2     W3    E6 2000-02-01 2000-02-10
```

Comment: Thanks, This works on the dataframes in the quesition. (I think you thew in an extra _on="DrillDate" though). When I run the equation with my actual data I get a "ValueError: left keys must be sorted", I sorted them but still wont work. There are duplicates of data and also datapoints that are not in both dataframes. does this matter? Thanks again.

Comment: Can you generate an input that fails?

Comment: Hi, sorry to get back so late. I saw the reason it was failing was because in my original table there were blank values on the open date. I removed these and the code ran with no error. The output is not what I was looking for though. It is not joining the values by the "Name" column. Instead it is just finding the closest date regardless of "Name". I have updated the code in the question above to show this. Is there a way to put one more piece of logic in to only interpolate if the Name columns are =? Thank you.

Comment: I believe inserting "by='Name' at then end makes it work.